# Implementing DDPG in tensorflow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow, keras, reinforcement-learning, tensorflow2.0, q-learning

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52340133/11204016

In the above answer, I'm stuck in 7th step.

How can we multiply dQ/dA and dA/dTheta?

- dQ/dA is of dimension of batch size.
- dA/dTheta is of dimensions of network weights (Thetas of Q netwok).